# Trouble building UACME executable

Tags: windows, visual-studio, security, binary, executable

I am trying to build the executable for this project
https://github.com/hfiref0x/UACME

The creator does not release compiled binaries (which is completely understandable) and I am trying to understand what to do exactly.
I follow a Youtube video to build the executable, but it doesn't work, since additional binary modules have to be built, see https://github.com/hfiref0x/UACME/issues/82

> Starting from 3.5 version all binary modules integrated to Akagi must be compiled before compiling Akagi and copied to the Akagi\Bin directory in previously encrypted state (use Naka for this purpose), there will be no more ready-to-use binaries included. Same goes to secrets blobs. To be able to automatically compile source you need to alter it.

Sadly there is no tutorial on that and I don't know where to start. I see there are several files in the \UACME\Source\Akagi\bin folder, which probably have to be built like the executable?

Instructions from the creator:

> To build working binary:
>
> - Compile payload units
> - Compile Naka module
> - Encrypt all payload units using Naka module
> - Generate secret blobs for these units using Naka module
> - Move compiled units and secret blobs to the Akagi\Bin directory
> - Rebuild Akagi

PS: I work in security and am learning about UAC and bypasses. I will not use this to do something illegitimate.

What I did so far:
I have a working Visual Studio with the SDKs installed, just like the creator instructed.
I imported the project and built the Akagi executable. Execution works but without the additional modules, what is supposed to happen does not happen.